# Module development - integrating custom content types

Tags: 7, entities

I want to create a module which would need custom content types from the cck module. I know in the .info I can say a dependency is the cck module.

How can I best have the module create the content type? I want this to be easily distributed rather than when I put it on a website I have to also create the content type using cck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create an export of a CCK content type to use in the module. For an example of this method see [How to create a CCK content type and fields from a module](http://drupal.org/node/1044248).

[Another exported CCK example](http://neminis.org/blog/drupal/programmatic-cck-content-types-updated/)

Comment: Features can be of great help as well setting up fields and configuration.