# Creating new content type (programmatically) with CCK fields as default

Tags: entities, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Module development - integrating custom content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/module-development-integrating-custom-content-types)

Is there any way to programmatically create a new content type with few CCK default fields?
I don't want to add those fields after I created the content type, but I want them to be delivered with my module instead
Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several suggestions about create CCK programatically (also can be seeking for CCK import content):

- Programmatically Create, Insert, and Update CCK Nodes: http://civicactions.com/blog/cck_import_and_update
- Creating Drupal CCK content programatically/ via API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772880/creating-drupal-cck-content-programatically-via-api
- Programmatically add CCK field to content type: http://drupal.org/node/702156
- Creating nodes with CCK-fields programmatically using drupal_execute() in D6: http://drupal.org/node/439090

I extract interesting comments from StackExchange:

> - ...The [Node Export module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) can generate sample code for creating a node
>     (complete with CCK fields) programatically.
> - There are a ton of modules that try to do the import thing right. Take
>     a look at a comparison of them http://groups.drupal.org/node/21338 ...

I hope this information be useful

Comment: Thank you very much, I have also discovered features module for this.